# How to loop through Models find from Where clause?

Tags: php, laravel, models

I am using PHP Laravel framework for my project and ran into a problem. What I need is finding all the users with specific user name. Here is my code for that.

```
        $keyword=$request['keywords'];
        $users=User::where('userName',$keyword);
        echo count($users);
        echo '<br>';
        echo count($users->get());
        foreach ($users->get() as $res){
            echo "results";
        }
```

This give the following output,

```
1
0
```

But the word "results" is not printed. What is the problem here how can I loop through the users object to print all the users. I am using Laravel 5.2

Comment: `User::where('userName',$keyword)->get()` this will return the total number of users.

Comment: It returns 0 users. I have breakdown the the statement you mentioned to two parts and print the count separately. After get() it has becomes 0.

Comment: `get()` return the exact result that means the query doesn't return db rows.

Comment: @user3888646 that's because there is not users with `userName = $request['keyword']`.

Comment: But my database has a user with the name I checked with. :-( And also do you know why it prints 1 and 0 in two instances ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `get()` or `paginate()` to get a collection first.

Then you usually iterate over the collection:

```
$users = User::where('userName', $request['keywords'])->get();
echo $users->count();
foreach ($users as $user){
    echo $user->id;
}
```

Comment: `foreach ($users->get() as $res){` he has done that in foreach loop